# NodeMailer does not work on Heroku but it works on LocalHost

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I tested with localhost:3000 and it works fine but when I try it on Heroku, it doesn't work. It didn't display any error.

This is my index.js:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered your email env on heroku? Or did you upload the .env file together?